# При импорте модуля @twilio/conversations выдают ошибки

Tags: react-native

Есть задача реализовать чат на RN с помощью @twilio/conversations . При импортирование этого модуля постоянно вылазят ошибки. Уже создавал новый проект тоже самое. В документации указанно что эта либа тестировалась под RN .
Пробовал удалять модули, чистить кеш итд.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

А если попробовать использовать конструкцию es6:

```
import Conversations from '@twilio/conversations'
```

конструкцию выше грузит модуль по требованию, а `require` как обработчик до файла доходит, тогда и грузит, поэтому могут быть случаи, что код который вызывает `require` загрузился быстрее, чем модуль к которому он пытается обратиться (надеюсь, что удалось +- объяснить)

Comment: Да по разному я пробовал ) И чистый проект создавал без typescript тоже самое . У коллеги с работы та же ошибка .

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать выполнить команду `npm install` или `yarn`. Понимаю, что вещь очевидная, но иногда об этом просто можно забыть.